# Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is not closed at this location

Tags: java

If I have the following code:

```
public XNameSupport implements AutoCloseable {
   private String localName;
   public String getLocalName(){
       return localName;
   }
}
public XElementSupport implements AutoCloseable {
   private XNameSupport name = new XNameSupport("root");
   private List<XElementSupport> child = new ArrayList<XElementSupport>();
   public XNameSupport getName(){
       return name;
   }
   Iterable<XElementSupport> elements(String name) throws Exception {
        List<XElementSupport> elements = new ArrayList<XElementSupport>();
        for (XElementSupport element : child) {
            if (element.getName().localName.equals(name))//Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is not closed at this location
                elements.add(element);
        }
        return elements;
    }
```

Under **element.getName().localName;** and shows me the following warning:

**Resource leak: 'unassigned Closeable value' is never closed**

If I access **localName** through method **getLocalName()** and the warning goes away.
I'm getting a warning through the field.
Is this an inconsistency (bug?) in Eclipse or am I missing some fundamental difference between the two scenarios?

Comment: What does `element.getName()` return? An `AutoCloseable`/`Closeable`?

Comment: Eclipse detects that you get an `AutoClosable` by calling a method and it doesn't know that it is a simple getter.

Comment: Why don't you do `try (XElementSupport element = new XElementSupport()) { return element.getName().localName; }`